# Count truthy objects in an array

Tags: ruby

I'd like to count truthy objects in an array. Since I can pass a block to count, the most idiomatic way I found was this:

```
[1, nil, 'foo', false, true].count { |i| i }
#=> 3
```

But I was wondering if there was a better way, especially using the syntax `count(&:something)`, because passing a full block here looks like overkill to me.

AFAIK, there is no `truthy?` method in Ruby, so I couldn't find how to achieve this.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, one might calculate an amount of `falsey`s `[1, nil, 'foo', false, true].count(&:!)` and subtract it from original array’s size :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With Ruby >= 2.2 you can use [Object#`itself`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#method-i-itself):

```
[1, nil, 'foo', false, true].count(&:itself)
#=> 3
```

Comment: Ruby 2.2.0 does that too... https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#method-i-itself

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
[1, nil, 'foo', false, true].count(true)
```

Comment: This only counts `true` objects. The goal was to count all truthy objects (ie. `1` and `'foo'` should also be counted.)